# When you type dir in terminal, the name file with space separate with symbol backslash \

Tags: command-line, directory, ls

#### Terminal Text

```
$ cd LALALA
~/LALALA $ dir
la\ la\ 1 la\ la\ 2
~/LALALA $
```

#### Directory Image

[image: Directory Image]

When I use `dir` command in terminal, the list of file show `\` (backslash) to separate their word (see: Terimanal Image). Whereas in the origin, there is no '\' (backslash) (see: Directory Image). How do I change this back to normal?

NB. I think the reason is because of the `pwd` command on the terminal. After I use the PWD command, this happens.

Comment: The backslashes are escaping the spaces in the names. It might be easier to see with the option `-l` "space minus ell": Try with `dir -l` or `ls -l`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you experience is *quoting*, `dir` has the `-N` or `--literal` option to disable it:

```
-N, --literal
       print entry names without quoting
```

The exact same applies to `ls`, just that it quotes the whole filenames with single quotes instead of escaping special characters (which can be triggered with `-b` or `--escape` for `ls` as well). Calling `ls` with `-N` disables this behaviour as well.

#### Example run

```
$ touch 'la la '{1,2}
$ dir
la\ la\ 1  la\ la\ 2
$ dir -N
la la 1  la la 2
$ ls
'la la 1'  'la la 2'
$ ls -b
la\ la\ 1  la\ la\ 2
$ ls -N
la la 1  la la 2
```

#### Further reading

- [`man dir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dir.1.html) and [`info dir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dir-invocation.html#dir-invocation)
- [Difference between 'dir' and 'ls' terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/103913/507051)
- Regarding the similar behaviour of `ls`: [Filenames with space showing as 'file name' after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1105867/507051)